# Hanging in the front end

Tags: front-end, system-performance

I'm writing some code and it's getting quite long, and I seem to get a lot of hanging in the front end when I'm trying to move the cursor to certain places with the mouse. I'm starting to think that there is a pattern to the places where I put the cursor that cause it to hang, but I don't know what the pattern is yet. I also get this message the pops up periodically, roughly every few hours while I'm working. I can't work out how it's related to what I'm doing at the time.

```
The string '"]' cannot be displayed with ShowStringCharacters->False due to an error in the string.
```

Sometimes I get the same message with '"}' instead of '"]', and sometimes I get "".

There was one point when my code seemed to get corrupted and some cells looked like a whole bunch of horrible box expressions. I copied the obviously corrupted parts from an old backup but maybe I missed something. I've tried running the following, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem

```
Needs["AuthorTools`"] 
NotebookRestore[]
```

I'm happy to provide the notebook if it's helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try setting this for the session to see if it fixes anything.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, CodeAssistOptions -> {"FloatingElementEnable" -> False}]
```

Code assist pops up defintions of functions upon hover-over.  If the package setup is convoluted the pop-ups can take a long time resulting on "Not Responding" messages.

If this solution works you can make it permanent by changing `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd`.  This option can also be found via the Option Inspector > Editing Options > Private Editing Options > CodeAssistOptions.

Comment: Ah yeah ok I think that all ties in now and the problem is with the tooltips. Is it possible to disable tooltips only for functions within a specific context?

Comment: @Joe I doubt it.  But you can probably identify which definitions are causing problems - LinkSnooper would help if it's not obvious, (via Evaluation menu > Start Kernel > LinkSnooper).

Comment: I see. What is LinkSnooper? My Evaluation->Start Kernel just contains Local, and two other kernels that I set up with the default options. Do I have to put LinkSnooper in the advanced options for one of my kernels or something?